# Pentaho CDF - MDX query: Showing data between months (parameters)

Tags: mdx, pentaho, cdf

I have two parameters: 'from month' and 'to month'. I would like to show data between those months. This is my situation:

```
with member [Measures].[Ordercount Y-1] as '([Year].PrevMember, [Measures].[Ordercount])'
member [Measures].[Growth] as IIF([Measures].[Ordercount Y-1] >0,
[Measures].[Ordercount]/[Measures].[Ordercount Y-1] *100,0)

select {[Measures].[Growth]} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY {[Year].[" +year+ "]} ON ROWS 
from [Ordercube]
```

Its a dialchart, I want to show the % of sales compared to last year in combination with a range between months.

In SQL it would be easy: Where month >= frommonth and month <= tomonth.
Since you can only slice once in a MDX query I don't know what to do.
I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you'd find that SQL wouldn't be quite as easy if the months weren't both in the same year :)

Either way, what you're looking for is something like this:

```
select NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Quantity]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [Markets].Children ON ROWS
from [SteelWheelsSales]
where {([Time].[2003].[QTR1] : [Time].[2004].[QTR2])}
```

This query was written against pentaho's data warehouse. I haven't the faintest clue what your data wharehouse looks like so I don't know what to use in the time dimension for your query, but it's the ([Time].[2003].[QTR1] : [Time].[2004].[QTR2]) syntax you're looking for, I think.

(disclaimer: I'm one of the CDF core developers, but my MDX sucks)

EDIT: In this particular case ([Range Operator Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146001.aspx)) the reference site isn't particularly explicit, but the MSDN reference site for MDX is pretty good, so here's the general [MDX Reference Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145595.aspx).